# Scala Type Tags - Fully qualified versus non-fully qualified

Tags: scala

I have some code (difficult to share and I've not been able to trivially replicate) which is throwing the following error:

```
found: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[com.company.some.package.Individ]
required: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Individ]
```

My code was unable to find a TypeTag, so I attempted to pass it explicitly. I.e. Instead of

```
abstract class Validator[T<: Product: TypeTag] {...}
class Validator[Individ] extends Validator[Individ] {...} // Implicits not found
```

I tried..

```
abstract class Validator[T<: Product](implicit tt: TypeTag[T]) {...}

implicit val tt = typeTag[Individ]
class Validator[Individ] extends Validator[Individ]()(tt) {...} // Wrong type, as above
```

`Individ` is just a case class

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want is

```
class IndividValidator extends Validator[Individ] {...}
```

When you write

```
class IndividValidator[Individ] extends Validator[Individ]()(tt)
```

you create a new generic class `IndividValidator` with a generic type parameter called `Individ` and it shadows your imported class. So the term `Individ` in the `extends Validator[Individ]` is matched to this type parameter rather than your `com.company.some.package.Individ`. To put it otherwise, this is the same code as

```
class IndividValidator[A] extends Validator[A]()(tt)
```

which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Ahhh yes - Thanks! When would one use the type parameter on the class?

Comment: @user2682459, I'm not sure I get your question. There are many cases where generic types are a good choice to reduce code duplication. Typical example is containers/collections library. Your base `Validator` class easily might be quite valid use as well.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I understand that `Validator[T]` is very useful, but when would I legitimately want to use `class IndividValidator[Individ] extends Validator[Individ]` (for example). As you correctly pointed out, I didn't want to parameterise `IndividValidator` here, but when might I want to do so?

Comment: @user2682459, I'd say I can't imagine a case when calling the generic parameter `Individ` is a good choice. I can imaging a case for something like `class IndividValidator[I <: Individ] extends Validator[I]` (not here `<: Individ` is a [generic bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html)): you have many different subclasses of `Individ` and you want to add some common to all of them validation logic to the base class. So then there will be `class SpecificIndivid extends Individ {...}` and `class SpecificIndividValidator[SpecificIndivid] extends Validator[SpecificIndivid]`